# Comparing dates in codeigniter & mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am totally beside myself that I can't figure this out myself, and have read every article I can get my hands on but alas still nothing. So I'm hoping someone can help.

I have a table that holds Shows. It has four time fields `show_start`(HH:MM AM/PM), `show_end`(HH:MM AM/PM), `show_start_actual`(HH:MM:SS), `show_end_actual`(HH:MM:SS). Also I have 7 columns named for the days of the week (sunday, monday, etc). Days of the week are either 1 or 0 to annotate whether the show is on that certain day. The `actual` columns are holding a 24 hour time format, the other times  are a `varchar` field.

I am trying to pull back the Show that is currently playing. The times are pretty basic (ie. 6:00 am - 10:00 am etc.) I have tried this in PHP and MySQL and nothing I am doing is working. I am sure there is an easy solution to this.

***This is my current rendition that is comparing the times in PHP, but I think it would be more efficient if I can actually pull it back in mySQL.***

Model

```
function on_air()
{
    $current_time = $this->convert_to_hour(date('g:i a',now()));
    $current_day_of_week = strtolower(date('l',now()));

    $mySQL = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM on_air_now");

    if($mySQL->num_rows() > 0 ){
        $mySQL = $mySQL->result();  
        foreach($mySQL as $row){

            eval('$db_day_of_week = $row->'.$current_day_of_week.';');
            $show_start = $this->convert_to_hour($row->show_start);
            $show_end = $this->convert_to_hour($row->show_end);

            if($current_time > $show_start && $current_time < $show_end && $db_day_of_week == 1){
                // If true then go at the show tables to  get info...
            }

        }
    }else{
        return FALSE;
    }
}

function convert_to_hour($str){
    $temp_arr = explode(":",$str);
    $arr_cnt = count($temp_arr)-1;
    $hour = $temp_arr[0];
    $min = explode(" ",$temp_arr[$arr_cnt]);
    $ampm = $min[1];
    if($ampm == 'pm' || $ampm == 'PM'){
        if($hour !== '12'){
        $hour = $hour+12;
        }
    }else{
        if($hour == '12'){
            $hour = 0;
        }
    }
    $new_time = $hour;
    return $new_time;
}
```

Update with data:

```
id,"datetime","show_name","sub_name","show_start","show_end","show_start_actual","show_end_actual","day_of_week",sunday,monday,tuesday,wednesday,thursday,friday,saturday,id_personalities,active,"date_added"
1,"2011-06-29 11:33:46","DJ","DJ","06:00 am","10:00 am","06:00:00","10:00:00",NULL,NULL,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,NULL
2,"2011-06-29 11:33:46","DJ","DJ","12:00 pm","03:00 pm","12:00:00","03:00:00",NULL,NULL,1,1,1,1,1,NULL,0,1,NULL
3,"2011-06-29 11:33:46","DJ","DJ","09:00 am","12:00 pm","09:00:00","12:00:00",NULL,NULL,0,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,1,NULL
4,"2011-06-29 11:35:17","DJ","DJ","03:00 pm","06:00 pm","15:00:00","18:00:00",NULL,NULL,1,1,1,1,1,0,NULL,1,NULL
5,"2011-06-29 11:35:39","Scott Stevens","Scott Stevens","06:00 pm","09:00 pm","18:00:00","21:00:00",NULL,NULL,0,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,1,"2011-06-21 6:15:57"
6,"2011-06-29 11:37:03","DJ","DJ","09:00 pm","12:00 am","21:00:00","00:00:00",NULL,NULL,0,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,1,"2011-06-21 6:18:10"
7,"2011-06-29 11:37:17","DJ","DJ","12:00 am","06:00 am","00:00:00","06:00:00",NULL,NULL,1,1,1,1,1,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
```

This is the CSV dump from the table.

Comment: To start with you can get rid of that eval() `$db_day_of_week = $row->$current_day_or_week;` should work

Comment: can you provide some example rows for your database, I want to try this out.

Comment: thanks guys. i took out the eval(); but still isn't getting through. this is killin me. :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can start by simplifying your database design. Below is a suggested alternative.

```
CREATE TABLE `show` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `show_name` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  `sub_name` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  `show_start` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `show_end` DATETIME NOT NULL,

/*    OTHER COLUMNS     */

  `datecreated` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `dateupdated` TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Unless the show is repeated many times in a week, you don't need the week's seven columns. Just get it from `show_start` itself using a [MySQL function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek).

Once you have done it, getting all the current shows is trivial using either MySQL or PHP. For example, to get all of today's shows using MySQL, the query would be

```
SELECT * FROM shows
WHERE DATE(NOW()) = DATE(`show_start`)
```

There are lot of [alternatives](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) for DATE in the above query as well.

Comment: Thanks for all of your input... I ended up changing the database and going with a totally different way of handling vs. using the older data. again thanks!!